# Should font end or back end create html output when Ajax get data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a page when button click use ajax append data

my question is should I let back end send JSON obj only and let front end JS create a html and placing all object's value into it and output in browser

OR

let back end create a html and front end only output it

I have also tried angularjs, get JSON obj -> template -> browser

Comment: if using angular usually all your templating is done for angular and you would send json and pass that to controller scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can make your server(back end) to send an XML or JSON data to the JS loaded in client's browser. Where the XML and JSON are pure data without any HTML tags. Your JS should process this data by adding proper HTML tags and display it.

   Notes:
   a. Faster server response.
   b. Response in xml or json in a standard way of data transfer, very useful when data is large.
   c. Both server side and client side coding is not so easy.
2. You can make your server (back end) to send an HTML response to the JS loaded in client's browser. Your JS can insert the HTML response to your existing HTML page.

   Notes:.
   a. Response may be slower, but server side coding is simpler.
   b. HTML response consume more bandwidth as it may have a larger size.
   c. Coding is simple and easy.

If I have written something wrong or confusing, hope other will edit this, :)

Comment: I used to creae html from server and let JS display it, since if I use JS to create html and add all value, it just a lots work, and sounds not very efficient

Comment: @BenjaminW no less efficient when using a javascript framework with integrated template engine and actually less work in many ways because it's easy to do data binding and not have to write code to do updates of the html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it both ways however I think it's better to have the backend just send the data and you inject that data into your view. The reason being is that it's easier to test your frontend with the backend stubbed out. You can also upgrade or replace your backend with a different platform without having to do a lot of rework. Your backend will also be easier to test if it returns JSON rather than HTML.